# Scala Unable to access jarfile

Tags: scala

I have the code:

```
val a = Seq("java","-jar \""+base.getCanonicalPath+"/sbt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar\"")

val proc = Process(a)

proc.!<(
new ProcessLogger {override def buffer[T](f: => T): T = f

override def out(s: => String): Unit = println(s)

override def err(s: => String): Unit = println(s)
 })
}
```

But when i try to run it, it outputs:

> Error: Unable to access jarfile "/home/remus32/.remus32/sbt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar"

but the path is correct, when i try to run it in terminal it works, so where is the problem?

Comment: permissions? You can check those with `ls -al /home/remus32/.remus32/sbt/sbt/bin/sbt-launch.jar`

Comment: Tried chmod -R 777 ~/.remus32/sbt, but still not working

Comment: Is there a reason you need to have the quotes inside your string?  Wouldn't you normally type `java -jar /path/to/file.jar`, sans quotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find two problems with your code:

1. Get rid of the quotes in the string (as a side note, if you were typing the quotes in terminal, many terminals use quotes as an alternative to having to escape special characters, so yours may have been doing that).
2. Make the path to the jar a separate argument from the `-jar` one.

The following works for me (I did modify the path to be that of a sbt-launch jar from my own system, obviously):

```
val a = Seq("java","-jar", "/Users/soong/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea13/sbt/sbt-launch.jar")
val proc = Process(a)
proc.!<(
    new ProcessLogger {override def buffer[T](f: => T): T = f

    override def out(s: => String): Unit = println(s)

    override def err(s: => String): Unit = println(s)
    })
```